# Where to `defineCustomElements(window);` in ionic vue photogallery app?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I have started learning ionic vue. I was following this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/your-first-app) . But i am stuck here ***Next, import @ionic/pwa-elements by editing src/main.ts.***

```js
// Above the createApp() line
import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';

// Call the element loader after the platform has been bootstrapped
defineCustomElements(window);
```

My question is where do I put the following line?

```js
// Call the element loader after the platform has been bootstrapped
defineCustomElements(window);
```

I tried this but id does not work

```js
router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app');
  defineCustomElements(window);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like import line, **Above the createApp() line**

```
import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';
defineCustomElements(window);

const app = createApp(App)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router);
```

Comment: It worked? Do you use Nuxt 3?